# http://localhost is getting forwarded

Tags: apache, xampp, symfony4

I am using Xampp and in my htdocs directoy I have a folder called 'task4u'. If I go to http://localhost, I'll get forwarded to the page of 'task4u' (which is a Symfony 4 application).

In htdocs I have now created a new folder for a new website but I still get forwarded to the directory 'task4u'.

I have checked the windows file 'hosts' but there is nothing related to this issue.

Where could that forwarding be set? Is that because of Symfony itself maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Windows host file contains only a redirect to 127.0.0.1 (loopback address) for "localhost" (or you can configure more redirects to 127.0.0.1).

You have to give a look to httpd.conf Apache file; it should be under this path for a XAMPP installation: *C:\XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf*. Open httpd.conf with a text editor and change it with your new directory path under **DocumentRoot C:/your/path** and **< Directory C:/your/path/>**

Remember to restart Apache server by XAMPP interface.

Comment: In http.conf the DocumentRoot is correct. It is `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"`

Comment: Ok @Reza. I hope that you have resolved by the edit of htdocs.